# toast not working in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toast

The Toast below is throwing and error.  Any thoughts on what might be wrong.  Everything else works fine.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final CopListdata coplistdata ;
    holder.coplistdata=copitems.get(position);
    holder.fooditem.setText(holder.coplistdata.get_itemname());
    holder.imageExpand.setImageResource(holder.coplistdata.getImageId());
    ;
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final CopListdata coplistdata ;
            onCopClickListner.onClicked(copitems.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(context(),"you clicked +coplistdata.get_itemname(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  .show(); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In place of context() you have to pass Application context.for more details you can go through this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: @TeleJim did the priblem solve???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this   `view.getcontext()`

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final CopListdata coplistdata ;
                onCopClickListner.onClicked(copitems.get(position));
                Toast.makeText(view.getcontext(),"you clicked"+coplistdata.get_itemname(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  .show(); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to closed double invented comma

```
Toast.makeText(context,"you    clicked"+coplistdata.get_itemname(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```